# osx style pop-up using SimpleModal jquery can't get it to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make simpleModal jquery script to work, but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe set of fresh eyes can help me? I'd more than appreciate :)

Test site is here: 
Login link should pop-up the hidden div.

Jquery I'm using is this:
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ (OSX Style Dialog)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I kind of figured it out. it was settings.js has reference to many plugins I didn't include in html. Putting them back fixed the problem. But it still doesn't work like example... cannot get tittle to slow in.

Comment: in your settings.js why don't you add all your code under window.load instead of writing .load again and again, if you haven't go your solution yet, you might want to consider writing a sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: no thanks :) I figured it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was settings.js has reference to many plugins I didn't include in html. Putting them back fixed the problem.